# Neo4J Aggregation count Globally and not per subgraph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here is my data model (conceptually):

```
(Person)-[:SEEN_AT_EVENT]->(Event)
```

Data:

```
CREATE (john:Person {name: 'John Smith'})
CREATE (jane:Person {name: 'Jane Smith'})
CREATE (a:Event {name: "Event A"})
CREATE (b:Event {name: "Event B"})
CREATE (c:Event {name: "Event C"})
CREATE (john)-[:SEEN_AT]->(a)
CREATE (john)-[:SEEN_AT]->(b)
CREATE (john)-[:SEEN_AT]->(c)
CREATE (jane)-[:SEEN_AT]->(a)
CREATE (jane)-[:SEEN_AT]->(b)
CREATE (jane)-[:SEEN_AT]->(c)
```

And a few examples:

```
"John Smith" seen at event "Event A"
"John Smith" seen at event "Event B"
"John Smith" seen at event "Event C"
"Jane Smith" seen at event "Event A"
"Jane Smith" seen at event "Event B"
"Jane Smith" seen at event "Event C"
```

I'd like to find out Persons who are seen together more than 2 times and retrieve the Person and Event nodes along with the relationship.

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[rel1:SEEN_AT]->(e:Event)<-[rel2:SEEN_AT]-(p1:Person) 
WITH p, rel1, e, rel2, p1, count(e) AS total_events_together 
RETURN  p, rel1, e, rel2, p1, total_events_together
```

This (as expected) shows me the individual paths (subgraphs) between John and Jane. The count is per subgraph (which is 1).

I want to use this count as a predicate to filter the paths (which I believe means that this count should be applied globally (at the graph level and not at the subgraph level)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the events per each pair of people at an event where one id is greater than the other so you do not double count. And instead of just getting the count, collect the event and each relationship in a separate object. Use the size of the collection to get only the joint events greater than two.

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[rel1:SEEN_AT]->(e:Event)<-[rel2:SEEN_AT]-(p1:Person) 
WHERE id(p) > id(p1)
WITH p, p1, collect( {event: e, rel1: rel1, rel2: rel2}) AS total_events_together
WHERE size (total_events_together) > 2
RETURN p, p1, total_events_together
```

Comment: Thanks! That made it! I never knew that the collect function could accommodate custom objects (created at runtime).